# Kafka Connect - JSON Converter - JDBC Sink Connector - Column Type JSON

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

use case is to store entire message (which is JSON) and key as a record in table which has two columns 'id' and 'data'.

The database is Postgres and it supports column type as JSON.

As per this article, supported types in JSONConverter are string, int64, etc
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-301%3A+Schema+Inferencing+for+JsonConverter

Is it possible to have type of data field as JSON which then can be stored in Postgres DB with column of type JSON.

```
schema = `{
"type":"struct",
"fields":[
    {"type":"string", "optional": false, "field":"id"},
    {"type":"string", "optional": false, "field":"data"}
]}`
```

Sample data payload is

```
"payload": { "id": 10000, "data": {"hello":"world"} }
```

Above will store data as text and expects column to be of type text in Postgres.
If the column on Postgres is of type JSON then the JDBC Sink Connector will throw an error.

Using JSON types on Postgres will help to create index on JSON fields and so forth. Is it possible to use JSONConverter along with JDBC Sink Converter appropriately for storing records with column type JSON.

Comment: What error does JDBC Sink Connector throws? Could you add some logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC  Sink Connector doesn't support PostgreSQL json, jsonb types. It support number of primitive types, datetimes.

At following page you can find mapping schema types to Databases types (PostgreSQL) https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.0/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html

Although, JDBC **Source** Connector supports json, jsonb types in some part - columns of such type won't be mapped to `STRUCT`, but will be mapped to `STRING` type.

Comment: It does support it now https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/46#issuecomment-1135209669

Answer (score 1):

Use `value.converter.schema.enable=true`, and send JSON data like this (with the schema as part of every message, and update the `payload` section with the actual message data), and it should work with the JDBC Sink.

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [{
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "id"
        }, {
            "type": "struct",
            "name": "data",
            "optional": false,
            "fields": [{
               "type": "string",
               "name": "hello",
               "optional":false
            }]
        }],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "foobar"
    },
    "payload": {
        "id": 10000,
        "data": {"hello":"world"}
    }
}
```

Notice that the fields > name entries map to the keys in the payload object, which are your column names

Or you could look into converting your clients to use Avro, and save yourself some network bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for writing. Sorry, my bad if I didn't explain it well, I meant that here data value is not a string 'bar' it itself is a JSON object for example "payload": {
        "id": 10000,
        "data": {"hello":"world"}
    }

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. The `data` would just have a `struct` schema.

Comment: if I have a pg schema name TESTDB and table name as Test, what would be the type and name under the schema. "fields" I believe are the column names right?

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you please help me how to add `timestamp` field in `struct`?

Comment: @NullPointer Also, please create a new post